# How to find a proper probabilistic formulation given the objective function terms?

Tags: machine-learning, probabilistic-computation

I want to pose a problem as maximisation of MAP probability $P(X,Y|Z)$ and I know which terms I want to have in the objective function. However, I am unable to combine these terms to form a joint probability distribution $P(X,Y,Z)\sim P(X,Y|Z)$. More specifically, $X=x_1...x_t$ and $Y=y_1...y_t$ are hidden variables and $Z=z_1...z_t$ are observations and I want the following terms to appear in the objective function:

$P(z_t|x_t,y_t)$

$P(y_t|y_{t-1})$

$P(x_t|x_{t-1},y_{t-1})$

$P(x_t,y_t)$ or $P(y_t|x_t)$ or $P(x_t|y_t)$ (as $P(x_t)$ and $P(y_t)$ are uniform)

How does one come about deriving the Bayesian network that would describe a probability distribution with these terms? Is there possibly a BN that is specifically suited for this scenario? How should one in general formulate such problems?

Thank you.